# Optimize getting counts of rows grouped by first letter in SQLite?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, indexing

My current query looks something like this:

`SELECT SUBSTR(name,1,1), COUNT(*) FROM files GROUP BY SUBSTR(name,1,1)`

But it's taking a pretty long time just to do counts on a table that's already indexed by the `name` column. I saw from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716364/sorting-sql-by-first-two-characters-of-fields) that some engines might not use indexes correctly for the SUBSTR function, and in fact, [sqlite will not use indexes for SUBSTR(string,1,1)](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg14666.html).

Is there any other approach that would utilize the index and net me some faster queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy that is consistent with your access pattern is to add a new indexed column "first_letter" to your table. Use a trigger on to set the value on insert and update. Then your query is a simple group by first_letter.

Answer (score 0):

Another strategy is to create a shadow table which contains an aggregation of the mother table. This isn't easy because it is your job as developer to keep the shadow table consistent with the mother table. Every delete, update or insert in table *files* needs to be accompanied by a change in the shadow table.

Databases like Oracle have support for materialized views to achieve this automatically but sqlite doesn't.