# SQL Order each first letter by date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I need a SQL query that returns all rows where name start with A, and order these by date. Then return all rows where name starts with B, and order these by date, etc. Also, sticky items need to be on top of the results. I need it to be one SQL query because of pagination. Can this be done? If so, how?

I really put in some effort but can't come close to a solution. Unfortunately I have no example SQL to use as a starting point.

**Database**

```
id | name | date        | sticky
1  | aa   | 12-16-2017  | 0
2  | ab   | 12-14-2017  | 0
3  | ac   | 12-15-2017  | 0
4  | ba   | 12-16-2017  | 0
5  | bb   | 12-14-2017  | 0
6  | bc   | 12-15-2017  | 1
```

**Result**

```
1 bc (sticky)
2 ab (start a order by date)
3 ac
4 aa
5 bb (start b order by date)
6 ba
```

Comment: Yes, this can be done. What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are tons of question here on SO that deal with ordering resultset. For example, this one shows how to sort by the first two letters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716364/sorting-sql-by-first-two-characters-of-fields, this one shows how to order by multiple criteria: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416880/sorting-multiple-fields-in-mysql So, your claim that there are no sql queries that you can use as a starting point is a pretty poor excuse.

Comment: No research effort.

Comment: I was looking into using WHILE and using LIKE 'A%'. Unfortunately this is really beyond my SQL skill level. I meant to say, that I have not come of with an example SQL query. And I did not found an example, sometimes it's hard to find something if you don't know what direction to look for.

Comment: @DavidLok sorry mate, but you can easy search for "mysql sort by first letter" or "mysql sort by multiple fields". These search expressions only require common sense, no technical knowledge is necessary. And if did try sg, then why not share that attempt with us? That would show that you indeed tried sg, and you are not just dumping your problem on us.

Comment: @shadow I thought this was more advanced then sorting by multiple fields. My mistake apparently. When you are thinking it the wrong direction, you will search in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to sort by the stick bit (descending), the first letter of the name and then the date:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     `mytable`
ORDER BY `sticky` DESC, LEFT(`name`, 1), `date`
```

Comment: Answering simple question showing no research effort just encourages people to come here and dump their work on us because they get an answer anyway.

Comment: @Shadow I've only posted 3 questions in 6 years. So I'm not the kind of guy that dumps his work. I guess i'm just really bad in searching for SQL solutions, I will work in that :-).